# Adding value from a pandas dataframe only if other value from the same row is True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas.

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
Date_1       Hour_1    id_1    Date_2       Hour_2    id_2    Date_3       Hour_3    id_3    
2019-12-04   00        ABC     2019-12-04   01        ABC     2019-12-04   02        ABC
2019-12-04   00        ABCD    2019-12-04   01        ABCD    2019-12-04   02        ABCD
2019-12-04   00        ABCDEF  2019-12-04   01        ABCDE   2019-12-04   02        ABCDEF
2019-12-04   03        ABCDEFG 2019-12-04   01        ABCDEFG 2019-12-04   02        ABCDEF
...
```

**My goal**

Is to check if `id_1` exists in `id_2`, `id_3`. And create a new dataframe where the structure would be the following:

```
Date_1       Hour_1    id_1    Date_2       Hour_2    Exists   Date_3       Hour_3    Exists    
2019-12-04   00        ABC     2019-12-04   01        True     2019-12-04   02        True
2019-12-04   00        ABCD    2019-12-04   01        True     2019-12-04   02        True
2019-12-04   00        ABCDEF                         False    2019-12-04   02        True
2019-12-04   03        ABCDEFG 2019-12-04   01        True                            False
```

The problem which I have right now is that I don't know how to include Date_2, Hour_2, Date_3, Hour_3 or exclude them depending if the id_2 and id_3 is True or False.

When I am creating my dataframe I simply add all each source of the information ( Date, Hour, id ) and I get large dataframe where I have Date_1-10, Hour_1-10, id_1-10.

```
final_export['Exists in id_2'] = final_data['id_1'].isin(final_data['id_2'])
final_export['Date from id_2'] = final_data['Date from id_2 other source']
final_export['Hour from id_2'] = final_data['Hour from id_2 other source']
```

When I use `.isin()` method it filters the data correctly but it does not change if the hour and date from the same row is included or not. For example if id_1 exists in id_3 I would have True and its date and hour, if it does not exists I would have False and date with hour would be empty.

At the moment when I use `.isin()` date and hour are not linked to the id_ value.

Let me know if the problem is explained correctly.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: why is Date 3 / Hour 3 true for id `'ABDEF'`

Comment: Because `ABDEF` exists in id_3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
mask_id2 = df.id_1 == df.id_2
mask_id3 = df.id_1 == df.id_3

df.id_2 = mask_id2
df.id_3 = mask_id3

df.loc[~mask_id2, ['Date_2', 'Hour_2']] = ""
df.loc[~mask_id3, ['Date_3', 'Hour_3']] = ""
```

Output:

```
       Date_1  Hour_1     id_1      Date_2 Hour_2   id_2      Date_3 Hour_3   id_3
0  2019-12-04       0      ABC  2019-12-04      1   True  2019-12-04      2   True
1  2019-12-04       0     ABCD  2019-12-04      1   True  2019-12-04      2   True
2  2019-12-04       0   ABCDEF                     False  2019-12-04      2   True
3  2019-12-04       3  ABCDEFG  2019-12-04      1   True                     False
```

Comment: For some reason I am getting
 ```Date_1 Hour_1 id_1 Date_2 Hour_2 id_2 Date_3 Hour_3 id_3
0 2019-12-04 00 ABC       False   False
1 2019-12-04 00 ABCD   False   False
2 2019-12-04 00 ABCDEF   False   False
3 2019-12-04 03 ABCDEFG   False   False``` in jupyter notebooks

Comment: Can you double check? I am using your exact data set. This shouldn't be environment-dependent.

Comment: And does this method itterate through whole column or only checks the values in the same row? Because in my dataframe values will be scattered and will not be found in the same row.

Comment: The equality check is element-wise. Instead you can mask it with `df.id_1.isin(df.id_2)` for instance if that's what you want.

Comment: So it would look like this: `mask_id2 = df.id_1.isin*df.id_2)`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest dividing the data frame into three data frames, each having id,date,hour and use merge function to merge the dataframes with the id as a value and assign null values where the id is not present

Answer (score 0):

try

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date_1": ["2019-12-04", "2019-12-04", "2019-12-04", "2019-12-04"],
    "Hour_1": ["00", "00", "00", "03"],
    "id_1": ["ABC", "ABCD", "ABCDEF", "ABCDEFG"],
    "Date_2": ["2019-12-04", "2019-12-04", "2019-12-04", "2019-12-04"],
    "Hour_2": ["01", "01", "01", "01"],
    "id_2": ["ABC", "ABCD", "ABCDE", "ABCDEFG"],
    "Date_3": ["2019-12-04", "2019-12-04", "2019-12-04", "2019-12-04"],
    "Hour_3": ["02", "02", "02", "02"],
    "id_3": ["ABC", "ABCD", "ABCDEF", "ABCDEF"],
})

ids = df["id_1"]
# You can choose whichever columns you want
df_1 = df.loc[df["id_1"].isin(ids), ["Date_1", "Hour_1", "id_1"]]
df_2 = df.loc[df["id_2"].isin(ids), ["Date_2", "Hour_2", "id_2"]]
df_3 = df.loc[df["id_3"].isin(ids), ["Date_3", "Hour_3", "id_3"]]

df_concat = pd.concat([df_1, df_2, df_3], axis=1)
```

output

```
Date_1  Hour_1  id_1    Date_2  Hour_2  id_2    Date_3  Hour_3  id_3
0   2019-12-04  00  ABC 2019-12-04  01  ABC 2019-12-04  02  ABC
1   2019-12-04  00  ABCD    2019-12-04  01  ABCD    2019-12-04  02  ABCD
2   2019-12-04  00  ABCDEF  NaN NaN NaN 2019-12-04  02  ABCDEF
3   2019-12-04  03  ABCDEFG 2019-12-04  01  ABCDEFG 2019-12-04  02  ABCDEF
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, `isin()` is the wrong function to use: it checks to see if a value of `id_1` is *anywhere* in the `id_2` or (`id_3`) column: it doesn't check if `id_1` is a substring of the value of `id_2` from the same row. Try the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
testdf = pd.DataFrame({
    "hour_1": ["00", "01"],
    "id_1":["ABC", "ABC"], 
    "id_2":["ABCD", "AB"], 
})
testdf["exists_in_2"] = testdf['id_1'].isin(testdf['id_2'])
testdf
```

To fix that bit first:

```
eltwise_contains =  lambda frag, text: frag in text
testdf["exists_in_2"] = testdf[['id_1', 'id_2']].apply(lambda x : eltwise_contains(*x), axis = 1)

testdf
```

Next, your problem: setting days and hours to the empty string if `id_1` doesn't exist in the values of `id_2` and `id_3` of the same row. We can use the same pattern as above: define a lambda expression that takes two inputs, then in the next line, extract two columns from the DataFrame, and apply a further lambda on that sub-DataFrame that passes an unpacked lambda-variable to the original lambda.

```
empty_string_if_false = lambda a_bool, val: val if a_bool else ""
testdf["hour_1"] = testdf[['exists_in_2', 'hour_1']].apply(lambda x : empty_string_if_false(*x), axis = 1)

testdf
```

Answer (score 0):

If Iron Hand's answer isn't what you were after this will give you a df in the format you had -

```
import pandas as pd

final_data = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date_1": ["2019-12-04", "2019-12-04", "2019-12-04", "2019-12-04"],"Hour_1": ["00", "00", "00", "03"],"id_1": ["ABC", "ABCD", "ABCDEF", "ABCDEFG"],
    "Date_2": ["2019-12-04", "2019-12-04", "2019-12-04", "2019-12-04"],"Hour_2": ["01", "01", "01", "01"],"id_2": ["ABC", "ABCD", "ABCDE", "ABCDEFG"],
    "Date_3": ["2019-12-04", "2019-12-04", "2019-12-04", "2019-12-04"],"Hour_3": ["02", "02", "02", "02"],"id_3": ["ABC", "ABCD", "ABCDEF", "ABCDEF"],
})

final_data['Exists in id_2'] = final_data['id_1'].isin(final_data['id_2'])
final_data['Exists in id_3'] = final_data['id_1'].isin(final_data['id_3'])    final_data['Date_2']=final_data.apply(lambda r: r['Date_2'] if r['Exists in id_2'] is True else '',axis=1)
final_data['Hour_2']=final_data.apply(lambda r: r['Hour_2'] if r['Exists in id_2'] is True else '',axis=1)
final_data['Date_2']=final_data.apply(lambda r: r['Date_2'] if r['Exists in id_2'] is True else '',axis=1)
final_data['Date_3']=final_data.apply(lambda r: r['Date_3'] if r['Exists in id_3'] is True else '',axis=1)
final_data['Hour_3']=final_data.apply(lambda r: r['Hour_3'] if r['Exists in id_3'] is True else '',axis=1)
print(final_data[['id_1','id_2','id_3','Hour_2','Hour_3']])
```

which gives a df with all the original info except id2, hour2 removed when id_2 is not in id1 and likewise for id3. Selected rows look like -

```
      id_1     id_2    id_3 Hour_2      Date_2 Hour_3      Date_3
0      ABC      ABC     ABC     01  2019-12-04     02  2019-12-04
1     ABCD     ABCD    ABCD     01  2019-12-04     02  2019-12-04
2   ABCDEF    ABCDE  ABCDEF                        02  2019-12-04
3  ABCDEFG  ABCDEFG  ABCDEF     01  2019-12-04
```